# gmapping creates no map

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I created a bagfile containing the data of a LaserScan and odometry published
in /tf.

According to rostopic echo the data is fine, by fine I mean the data is changing and in the right form.

Still, for some reason I don't know, this warning occurs:

> [ WARN] [1243531255.142345324]:
> MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped
> 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the
> [ros.gmapping.message_notifier]
> rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more
> information.

Anyone there, who had the same problem?

P.S.:
I know, there warning contains information about what to do, but I haven't figured out, what it wants me to do...so explanations what "turn the rosconsole logger" means and how it is done are also welcome :-)

Edit:
According to another question asked here, it might be some issue concerning time stamps, therefore I modified my /scan topic by setting the header.stamp to ros::Time::now(), which is exactly what I do with the /odom's header...

Edit2:
[link text](http://speedy.sh/tCNDv/roundmap2.bag)

That is one of the bagfiles I recorded :-)

Edit3:
[testfile](http://speedy.sh/zVx9p/lasttry.bag)
here is a file with a static transform publisher - still all odom data is dropped,
and I really can't make out the difference to [the tutorial's bagfile](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData) - at least I've found nothing that should matter....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43901/gmapping-creates-no-map/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-09-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-09-16**:
could you post the bagfile? It is hard to tell what's going on without it...

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-16**:
done, thanks for your affords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you have set up everything correctly for using simulation time (so the timestamps from the bagfile are used)? Also see [the Clock documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock) regarding this. You have start a roscore, set the parameter:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

then start anything else you need and then play your bagfile with the --clock option:

```
rosbag play [your_bagfile] --clock
```

As for the rosconsole logger question, you can use the [rxconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole) tool to set different log levels for different nodes and get more debug output.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-16**:
Short question: Do I have to set use_sim_time before recording the data - because if I follow your instructions still all the odom messages are dropped(rxconsole doesn't really help, seems to be some issue in /tf messagefilter - given codeline is just the output).

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2017-09-07**:
I am facing the same problem and I am using the use_sim_time parameter correctly. I have added a static transform publisher between-  base_link and map, & map and odom. This is what i run-

```
  rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan _odom_frame:=odom _base_frame:=base_link _map_frame:=map
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. So, you have the robot's \scan topic publishing on the wrong frame. You need to publish the data on the same frame as the robot. So, try a [static transform publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf). This will let gmapping know where the laser is with respect to the robot's coordinate system. Hope this was of use to you!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-16**:
http://speedy.sh/zVx9p/lasttry.bag

still get the error

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your tf tree is apparently not complete. Have a look at the [gmapping wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping). You can find a section on required tf transforms at the bottom.

First, the system needs to be able to transform from your laser sensor into base link. You seem to publish a transform from base_link to base_laser, but your sensor data on the `scan` topic is in frame `openni_depth_frame`, i.e. gmapping will not be able to transform the sensor data correctly. Instead of having a static_transform_publisher from `base_link` to `base_laser`, publish the transform from `base_link` to `openni_depth_frame`.

Second, you don't seem to have an odom transform. However, gmapping requires valid odometry. Normally, the transform is published by your robot's base driver that also publishes on the /odom topic. Make sure you have that set up correctly, otherwise gmapping won't work.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-17**:
My odom node is basically http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom ,
so there should be everything needed?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-17**:
In the bag you provide I cannot see the odom->base_link transform. Verify that your odom node is really working.

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-17**:
http://speedy.sh/c7p5J/test2.bag <- would you mind looking at this bagfile, I tried to implement your solution. I am pretty sure that my odom node works, especially as it is nearly 1:1 the example code for fake odom data from the navigation stack(which uses gmapping, so that should be fine)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-17**:
It looks like your tf tree is somehow messed up. `rosrun tf view_frames` shows that you seem to have two root,s, base_footprint and odom. I don't know which node publishes the transform base_footprint->base_link but either odom should publish odom->base_footprint or you should get rid of it.

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-17**:
Can't thank you enough, finally got everything to work(my maps look like crap, but I suppose thats due to the recorded data).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-17**:
Great! If my answer was correct, please mark it so (little check under the up/downvote buttons).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case it didn't work if I had recorded the bagfile with

```
$ rosbag record -O testbag1.bag scan tf
```

but it did work quick & dirty when I had used

```
$ rosbag record -a
```

I am very new to ROS and I only assume there is another necessary topic recorded among all topics when using "-a" which is related to tf transform as Lorenz and allenh1 mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [obernoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/40050/obernoob/) with karma: 31 on 2019-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BesterJester](https://answers.ros.org/users/56384/besterjester/) on 2020-11-16**:
I was having the same issue, and doing `rosbag record -a` fixed it.  After that, I did some testing and found that the other necessary topic is `/tf_static`. This has something to do with the change to `tf2` that occurred since the `Hydro` version.
http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration#Addition_of_.2BAC8-tf_static_topic